# Python Flask app, AJAX post getting 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to learn how to use AJAX and I cannot figure out why this doesn't work.

I'm getting a 400 BAD REQUEST with an AJAX call, not sure why.

Here's the ajax call (in dashboard.html):

```
$('#program-select').change
(
    function()
    {
        var program = $('program-select').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url_for('setup') }}',
            data: { program_name: program },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response)
            {
                $('#setup-content').html(response);
            },
            error: function(error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            }

        });
    }
)
```

And here's the view:

```
@app.route('/dashboard/', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    user_id = current_user.id
current_program = program.get_current_program_by_user(user_id)
return render_template('dashboard.html', current_program=current_program)


@app.route('/setup/', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def setup():
    program_name = request.form['program_name']
    print(program_name)
    return program_name
```

Initially I thought it was an issue because the AJAX is trying to post to a different route, but if I refactor it to post to **dashboard** it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The jQuery selector `$('program-select')` is probably missing a `#`.  There is no `program-select` tag in HTML.

Comment: @Wombatz Damn, you're right!  Works now.  Pays to have a second set of eyes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

credit to @Wombatz, I was missing the # in the jQuery selector.  Added and works now.